# Profiling in IntelliJ using Java Flight Recorder error

Tags: intellij-idea, profiler, java-16

I have some slow tests and I would like to figure out why they are slow. So I tried profiling them with the Java Flight Recorder in IntelliJ. The test run green but the profiler gives no output.

**Setup**:

- IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)
- AdoptOpenJDK-16.0.1+9
- Junit 5.7.2
- macOS Big Sur
- I've created a new, empty folder in my home directory and configured it under "Profiler" > "Settings" > "Change Snapshot folder..."

**Error**:

> Profiler error: Cannot parse the dump file: /Users/me/myDirectory/TestName_date_time.jfr (No such file or directory)

And indeed, this file (nor any other in this directory) was created.

The test was started with the following **command**:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-16-openj9.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=55496:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=name="TestName_date_time",settings="default",dumponexit=true,filename="/Users/me/myDirectory/TestName_date_time.jfr" -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=2048 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath [...] com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 my.package.VerySlowTest
```

How can I fix my setup to be able to run the profiler?

Note: Trying to run it with an Async Profiler gives a similar error.

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the sample snapshot to reprouce. See if a different JDK vendor works better.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder! While reporting, I stumbled upon this existing issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-17707
I guess my problem is the same. However, I did not find a workaround.